# Digibyte Wallet Hash

Tags: altcoin, wallet-security, passphrase

I recently invested in digibyte.
As someone of IT-security field, I'd love to know how the passphrase is stored in digibytes wallet.dat.
The [Bitcoin2John](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/bitcoin2john.py) doesn't work on it and hashcat, too, has no support for the wallet.
I couldn't find any information on how storage is done, so I'm asking you.
Best wishes and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with digibyte's wallet implementation specifically, but I can probably shed some general light:

Your passphrase is not stored in the wallet.dat - the passphrase is the *encryption key* that can be used to decrypt the wallet.dat. The wallet.dat itself stores private keys that can be used to sign transactions with the associated addresses.

When you run JTR or hashcat on the wallet.dat, you are brute forcing the passphrase itself to gain access to the private keys inside the wallet (trying to find a passphrase that when used as a decryption key is successfully able to decrypt the wallet)

Briefly looking at the digibyte core wallet, the wallet.dat appears to be in a standard format just like for any other wallet based on Bitcoin Core. You should start here if you want to know more about what information is stored inside the wallet.dat and how (look under Bitcoin Core): https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet

If Bitcoin2John and hashcat don't work on the wallet.dat, this is probably due to minor differences in storage, but it should be fundamentally the same.